# Xamarin Forms ListView in ScrollView - Android disable scrolling in listview

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am facing problem when using a ListView inside a Scrollview in Android (via Xamarin Forms).

I am calculating the height of the listview based on item source and a row height but i can still scroll inside the listview :

[image]

The listview is the white area contained in the scrollview, with few labels below, so we can scroll :

[image]

But in Android we can also scroll inside the listview itself :

[image]

I tried to catch the move event in a custom renderer :

```
public class CustomListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    public CustomListViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var customListView = Element as CustomListView;
        if (customListView == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (customListView.IsScrollingEnable == false)
        {
            Control.Touch += ListView_Touch;
        }
    }

    private void ListView_Touch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Move)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This can solve the space issue but if the user scroll from listview area with touch, the global scrollview doesn't work (you can only scroll with touch from Aqua Blue area).

Is there a way to disable the scroll in the listview without affect the parent scrollview ? The link to the sample project to reproduce the issue : https://1drv.ms/u/s!An8JKHwJo47up2ss_6pdzlXOhtDz?e=GdXrbf

Comment: you shouldn't nest scrollable views, and LIstView is inherently scrollable

Answer (score 1):

Like Jason said, you could use the Listview directly.

With your code, you could set `setScrollContainer` to false in custom renderer.

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement == null)
            return;

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.SetScrollContainer(false);
        }
    }
```

[image]